# How to keep an object inside a html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

This is the update function of my player object in a 'game'. I'd like to keep the player inside of the canvas, and while this code somewhat works, the player can intersect halfway through the top and left sides of the canvas. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
update()
    {
        if (keystate[LeftArrow] || keystate[AKey]) this.x -= 5;
        if (keystate[RightArrow] || keystate[DKey]) this.x += 5;
        if (keystate[UpArrow] || keystate[WKey]) this.y -= 5;
        if (keystate[DownArrow] || keystate[SKey]) this.y += 5;
        this.x = Math.max(Math.min(this.x, cvs.width - this.diameter), 0);
        this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, cvs.height - this.diameter), 0);
    },
```

EDIT: Here's the [JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/fixikoviqu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your player goes halfway over the boundary because the coordinates for your player are at the center of the circle. When either of them are zero, it will mean that the center of the player's circle will be along an axis.

Instead you should test for this.

`if (player.x - player.radius < 0) { player.x = player.radius; }`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
   void function() {
   
    "use strict";
    
    var canvasWidth = 180;
    var canvasHeight = 160;

    function Player(x,y,r) {
     this.x = x || 0;
     this.y = y || 0;
     this.r = r || 0;
     this.up = false;
     this.down = false;
     this.left = false;
     this.right = false;
    }
    
    Player.prototype = {
     MOVE_SPEED: 3.0,
    
     tick: function() {
      // Movement updates
      if (this.up) { this.y -= this.MOVE_SPEED; }
      if (this.down) { this.y += this.MOVE_SPEED; }
      if (this.left) { this.x -= this.MOVE_SPEED; }
      if (this.right) { this.x += this.MOVE_SPEED; }
      
      // Keep within canvas bounds
      if (this.x - this.r < 0.0) {
       this.x = this.r;
      }
      
      if (this.x + this.r > canvasWidth) {
       this.x = canvasWidth - this.r;
      }
      
      if (this.y - this.r < 0.0) {
       this.y = this.r;
      }
      
      if (this.y + this.r > canvasHeight) {
       this.y = canvasHeight - this.r;
      }
     },
     
     render: function(ctx) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r,this.y);
      ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0.0,2.0 * Math.PI,false);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
     }
    };
    
    var canvas = null;
    var ctx = null;
    var player = null;
    
    onload = function() {
     canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     canvas.width = canvasWidth;
     canvas.height = canvasHeight;
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     player = new Player(90,80,10);
     
     loop();
    }
    
    onkeydown = function(e) {
     switch(e.key.toLowerCase()) {
      case "w": player.up = true; break;
      case "s": player.down = true; break;
      case "a": player.left = true; break;
      case "d": player.right = true; break;
     }
    }
    
    onkeyup = function(e) {
     switch(e.key.toLowerCase()) {
      case "w": player.up = false; break;
      case "s": player.down = false; break;
      case "a": player.left = false; break;
      case "d": player.right = false; break;
     }
    }
    
    function loop() {
     // Tick
     player.tick();
     
     // Render
     ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
     
     player.render(ctx);
     
     //
     requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
   
   }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```